# Visual studios on windows server 2012

Tags: visual-studio

my Visual studio stopped working so i searched for a way to repair it, but couldn't load the installer, so i tried uninstalling and reinstalling. But once i tried to reinstall i got this Error:
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGIYm.png)

it's on a windows server 2012 Foundation. So i got the Installer going using the Cmd.

But it's blank looking like this([Blank Installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jEq4.png)).
have you ever experienced anything similar?

Best Regards and have a nice Monday.

Comment: The Foundation edition is indeed not among the [supported editions of Windows Server 2012](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs#visual-studio-2017-system-requirements).

Comment: hmm :/ i  had it installed and running perfectly for around a year.

Comment: But if so is there a workaround ? Always worked on this so i would prefer to keep doing so.